# Assign values between 0 and N -1 for a vector of length L with N different elements in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a 1-D tensor T of length L which has just N different values, how can I convert it to a tensor T2 of length L with values between 0 and N - 1 corresponding to the values of the original tensor T.
Example:

```
T  = [45, 58, 72, 33, 45, 58, 58, 33]
T2 = [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  1,  3]
```

The ordering is not important for example this also would be OK:

```
T2 = [1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0 , 0, 3]
```

Comment: Could you add an appropriate language tag please?

Comment: Perhaps check `tf.unique`.

Comment: Hi Siavash, I'm a software engineer at Google and I'd like to include a screenshot of this question in a research paper we're writing, to showcase some representative questions about TensorFlow. If that's alright with you, could you release your question under a permissive license? A comment saying e.g. "I license this StackOverflow question under the Apache License 2.0" would be sufficient for us. Thanks, David

Comment: I license this StackOverflow question under the Apache License 2.0.

Comment: For the research paper of @DavidBieber that uses this question, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09040.pdf)  and [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/tensorflow-coder/blob/master/TF-Coder_Colab.ipynb#scrollTo=DCvkqaXs4fyU&line=1&uniqifier=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

tf.unique(T)[1]

tf.unique_with_counts(T)[1]